# iOS - Broken iMessage Link Sharing

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, imessage

I am trying to share an URL via iMessage.The problem is when I sent it the URL breaks up into domains & remaining URL and some URL works properly

Link 1

> https://www.americanexpress.com/india/mumbai/dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPUludmFsaWRlbnN0cmElQzMlOUZlKzExNDtsYXQ9NTIuNTMwNzQ7bG9uPTEzLjM4NDI2O3N0cmVldD1JbnZhbGlkZW5zdHJhJUMzJTlGZTtob3VzZT0xMTQ7Y2l0eT1CZXJsaW47cG9zdGFsQ29kZT0xMDExNTtjb3VudHJ5PURFVTtkaXN0cmljdD1NaXR0ZTtzdGF0ZUNvZGU9QmVybGluO2NvdW50eT1CZXJsaW47Y2F0ZWdvcnlJZD1idWlsZGluZztzb3VyY2VTeXN0ZW09aW50ZXJuYWw

Link 2

> https://www.google.com/india/mumbai/search?q=stackoverflow

Screenshot[image]

As you can see Link 1 breaks into 2, while link 2 is sent properly

Is the link preview broken or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It might be an iOS issue, not necessarily something you're doing wrong. Even copying & pasting it has the same result. I converted the link into a short url via https://bitly.com/ and it seems to work as intended

Comment: bitly works in copy-paste only, once u share it in-app its the same stuff again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the reason or fix the issue but found a workaround to send links. Send the links in the following manner
<SOME_PREFIX>
In this way, the Link Preview doesn't work and the link can be shared without breaking the text
Eg:

> Check this Amex Card:\n
> https://www.americanexpress.com/india/mumbai/dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPUludmFsaWRlbnN0cmElQzMlOUZlKzExNDtsYXQ9NTIuNTMwNzQ7bG9uPTEzLjM4NDI2O3N0cmVldD1JbnZhbGlkZW5zdHJhJUMzJTlGZTtob3VzZT0xMTQ7Y2l0eT1CZXJsaW47cG9zdGFsQ29kZT0xMDExNTtjb3VudHJ5PURFVTtkaXN0cmljdD1NaXR0ZTtzdGF0ZUNvZGU9QmVybGluO2NvdW50eT1CZXJsaW47Y2F0ZWdvcnlJZD1idWlsZGluZztzb3VyY2VTeXN0ZW09aW50ZXJuYWw